# Apache Echart 3D Surface - not rendering

Tags: echarts

I am new to to Echarts(4.8)
Am using this as part of requirement where am stuck with rendering 3d Surface
Have followed example but not what I am looking for
Also I dint find any API documentation for 3D surface [here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=simple-surface&gl=1)

Have tried 2D curves, works perfectly
On similar line following 3D Surface is not getting rendered

Here is my test json

```
option = {
tooltip: {},
backgroundColor: '#fff',
visualMap: {
    show: false,
    dimension: 2,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    inRange: {
        color: ['#313695', '#4575b4', '#74add1', '#abd9e9', '#e0f3f8', '#ffffbf', '#fee090', '#fdae61', '#f46d43', '#d73027', '#a50026']
    }
},
xAxis3D: {
    type: 'value'
},
yAxis3D: {
    type: 'value'
},
zAxis3D: {
    type: 'value'
},
grid3D: {
    viewControl: {
        // projection: 'orthographic'
    }
},
series: [{
    "name":"test",
    "type":"surface",
    "data":[
        [
           "1",
           "10",
           "100"
        ],
        [
           "2",
           "20",
           "200"
        ],
        [
           "3",
           "30",
           "300"
        ]
     ],
}]
```

}

I must be missing something , any lead would really be helpful
Thanks much in advance ( apologies for bad formatting )

Answer (score 0):

It was data issue also gl package was missing which I think we need to import while along with echart
Thanks